# how to make a video from extracted frames?

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, frame

I extracted the video frames into a folder called "images". After getting images saved in my folder, I use the following code to create the video again. I get the video but the frames are ordered randomly, how can I arrange them in sequential order? thanks for the post

```
import cv2
import os


image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

please advise, how do I fix this? I'd like the videos to be at the same rate as the original video, and frames to be in sequential order.

Comment: Read them in the order like you write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Print your `images` list and look at the order of your images? Are they sorted?
2. What's the filename of your images? It's helpful to choose an increasing number like `00001.jpg` and `00002.jpg` instead of `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` this can mess up sorting.

   3. Sort the images after reading from os.listdir('.'): 
      This is an example with pathlib library.

```py
for filename in sorted([e for e in path.iterdir() if e.is_file() and str(e).endswith(".png")]):
    print(filename)
    img = cv2.imread(str(filename))
    img_array.append(img)
```

Or just using: 
`for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try instead of saving images and load them again, make video captures from your source video and pass it to out object (demo_output.avi in this case) ...something like this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('path to video/video.mp4')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
ret, frame = cap.read()
fps_video=cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
height,width = frame.shape[:2]
out = cv2.VideoWriter('demo_output.avi',fourcc, fps_video, (width,height)) ##can be set with your width,height values




while ret:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=1.0, fy=1.0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    out.write(frame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want images and then save video file:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('path to video/video.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
fps_video = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
height,width = image.shape[:2]
count = 0
while success:

    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file      
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1

vidcap.release()
lista = [[x[5:-4],x] for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('jpg')]

result=[]
for x in lista:
    t1,t2 = np.int(x[0]),x[1]
    result.append([t1,t2])

result.sort()

#recording video back
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('demo_output.avi',fourcc, fps_video, (width,height)) ##can be set with your width,height values

for img in result:
    frame = cv2.imread(img[1])
    out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

Comment: It does not work, even does not play the output video.

Comment: Just made some changes to write output video with the same width and height as original source video

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I have images in my folder and I want to make a video out of them, I'd like my video to be sequential as my images" or image names" are in order.

Comment: In the code i wrote (after UPDATE section), I created .jpg images frame by frame with a unique ID (given by count variable). After that I use lista = [[x[5:-4],x] for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith('jpg')] to read them back( X[5:-4] depends on how is named your current directory/path).Then I order the list using .sort, and put them back to video. I do not know how your images names are, so that´s why I make the previous step of save them using count variable. If this doesn´t work for you, could you specify what kind of names have your images. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement needs you to store the frames, try this

```
import cv2
import os


image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

for i in range(len(images)):
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, 'a'+str(i)+'.jpg')))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: @soumuth, the output video is not playable, could you please fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `glob` for listing files and sort the list. I have edited your code using glob. (Assuming your filenames of images are in the sequence you want)

```
import cv2
import os
import glob

video_name = 'video.avi'

images = glob.glob('images/*.jpg')
images.sort()

frame = cv2.imread(images[0])
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(image))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: images.sort()
 does not sort them, I still get some random images inside the video.

Comment: what are the names of the images saved like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need natural sorting, so try [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) library:

```
from natsort import natsorted

images = natsorted(images)
```

Install using pip:

```
pip install natsort
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with me

```
import cv2
import os


image_folder = 'c:\\m\\'
video_name = 'c:\\m\\avideo.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]


frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

#1 fps
#video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))


#25 fps
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 25, (width,height))

for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

materials and result [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/113tBYqjvbZtriwXXB9u0CtXYBEdnNNmL/view?usp=sharing)